# Any way to make this sort function faster?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

so right now im trying to filter thru around 12k users, around 1k+ a day. MongoDB with monk. And using this sorting code.

```
class User {
constructor(doc) {
    this.username = doc.username
    this.kills = doc.kills;
    this.deaths = doc.deaths;
}};

let res = await Calls.getAllUsers()

let users = res.map((doc) => new User(doc));

const sorted = users.sort((a, b) => b.kills - a.kills);

const whereIam = sorted.indexOf(users.find((u) => u.username === user_grab)) + 1;
```

The whereIam variable is killing performance. Around 20 seconds every query.

Comment: Why not (1) use `findIndex` and (2) do all of that inside MongoDB?

Comment: it is above all a problem of data structure; yours can only ruin performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just append `.sort({ kills: -1 })` to the mongo query you used inside `await Calls.getAllUsers()` to get all the users sorted by kills in descending order.

Reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/orderby/